# Golang - Is there a bcadd/bcsub package?

Tags: php, go, steam

Is there a package in golang similar to the PHP functions [bcsub](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcsub.php), [bcadd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) etc.?

I am trying to write the following function from php to golang.

```
function convertToSteamID($communityID) {
    // See if the second number in the steamid (the auth server) is 0 or 1. Odd is 1, even is 0
    $authserver = bcsub($communityID, '76561197960265728') & 1;
    // Get the third number of the steamid
    $authid = (bcsub($communityID, '76561197960265728')-$authserver)/2;
    // Concatenate the STEAM_ prefix and the first number, which is always 0, as well as colons with the other two numbers
    return "STEAM_0:$authserver:$authid";
}
```

Comment: give an example of $communityID

Comment: So I'm trying to convert STEAM_0:0:86173181 to 76561198132612090 using the php function above, except in golang.

Comment: Not exactly? hmmmmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float):

```
var (
    magic, _ = new(big.Int).SetString("76561197960265728", 10)
    one      = big.NewInt(1)
    two      = big.NewInt(2)
)

func commIDToSteamID(ids string) string {
    id, _ := new(big.Int).SetString(ids, 10)
    id = id.Sub(id, magic)
    isServer := new(big.Int).And(id, one)
    id = id.Sub(id, isServer)
    id = id.Div(id, two)
    return "STEAM_0:" + isServer.String() + ":" + id.String()
}

func steamIDToCommID(ids string) string {
    p := strings.Split(ids, ":")
    id, _ := new(big.Int).SetString(p[2], 10)
    id = id.Mul(id, two)
    id = id.Add(id, magic)
    auth, _ := new(big.Int).SetString(p[1], 10)
    return id.Add(id, auth).String()
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/fEPPXax6j2)

- *edit*: added the reverse function as well

Comment: I am going to test this out now. Thank you!

Comment: @Acidic i posted a more optimized version

Comment: Yep thank you. I tried it out and it returns a lot of text and the most helpful of which I could find was "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" and it exit's with status 2 if that's any help.

Comment: tried it with what? the playground link I posted works with the id you provided

Comment: Ah yeah whoops I was entering the wrong id in the argument. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108009/discussion-between-acidic-and-oneofone).